# Socket.io is not served in /socket.io/socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, http-status-code-404

i've read  the answers here about my problem in node.js, but my problem persists. With socket.io in the server, everything looks ok, but in client side, chrome says:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
localhost:3382/socket.io/socket.io.js

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var _io = require("socket.io");

var PORT = 3382;

var app = express();

app.listen(PORT, function(){
console.log("Listening from "+PORT);
});

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = _io.listen(server);
```

With jade i have:

```
script(src='/js/jquery.js')
script(src='/js/chat.js')
script(src="socket.io/socket.io.js")
```

I have the folder js in a folder static, it works ok. I don't know if it's because the versions (node -v show v0.8.16), how do i see versions of express and socket.io?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read through http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.listen, note how `app.listen` is defined.

In short: replace `app.listen` with `server.listen`.

Comment: woww, it's not easy for me to find documentation in english, i hope somebody translate too many more documents to spanish soon, thank you.

I hope this won't change much later.
Thanks a lot. I works like this :

    var server = http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, function(){
 console.log("Listening from "+PORT);
    });